# node.js req.body empty when sending from java with httpPost

Tags: java, android, node.js

When I'm trying to send some json to my node.js server req.body is empty and I have no idea why. The headers I'm sending are received.

This is the java code:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json, "UTF8");

        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("test", "test");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

And this is the node.js code:

```
exports.checkMail = function(req, res) {
    var user = req.body;
    var header = req.headers;
    var email = user.email;
    db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({'email':email}, function(err, item) {
            if (item) {
                res.send({'error':0, 'message':'email available'});
            } else {
                res.send({'error':4, 'message':'email already taken'});
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Any ideas of what I might be missing?

EDIT:

Sorry forgot to mention. I'm using Express.
And the json i'm sending is:

```
{"email":"email@email.com"}
```

What I get from req.body is just: {}

EDIT2:

app.js

```
    var express = require('express'),
        post = require('./routes/posts'),
        user = require('./routes/user');

    var app = express();

    app.configure(function () {
        app.use(express.logger('dev'));
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        //app.use(express.json());
        //app.use(express.urlencoded());
    });

    app.get('/auth',            user.login); 
    app.post('/auth',           user.addUser);
    app.put('/auth/:id',        user.updateUser); 
    app.post('/checkmail',      user.checkMail);  
    app.post('/reset',          user.resetPassword); 

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log('Listening on port 8080...');
```

Comment: What middleware do you have?

Comment: Are you using `express`? What do you get when you log `req.body` and `req.headers`?

Comment: @vmx if I ask for req.header.test I get test. For body just {}. Yes, using express

Comment: Do you have `app.use(express.bodyParser())` in your `app.js`? Although , you can include `app.use(express.json())` alone as you're only making json request

Comment: Yup I have bodyparser included. If i use: curl -i -X POST -H 'Conten--header "test: test" -d '{"email": "email@email.com"}' http://ipadress:3000/email ----- then it works fine

Comment: If `curl` works, that suggests your node server is running fine, maybe you need to fix the json post from Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late to answer, but if anybody has this same problem this is what worked for me:

```
//It is important that if we are sending a Content-Type application/json, the entity has to receive a json 
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
js.put("key", value);
String url = "http://mylocalhosturl";
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(js.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);

//Setting the content type is very important
entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
entity.setContentType("application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);

//Execute and get the response.
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Hope this helps to someone.

Comment: Hello! But what if you don't have option to edit java server, how you can fix this problem on nodejs server?

Answer (score 0):

You `app.js` file should have these middleares included;

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

// app configs; include these;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

// other configurations

app.use(app.router)

// ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added json and urlencoded but now the log doesn't work. SO I cant see if i receive anything in body.

Comment: Can you do a dummy post to `http://requestb.in/19ygnps1` from your java code? You can visit http://requestb.in/19ygnps1?inspect to see if the request was successful.

Comment: Yes, I saw your requestb.in post. This is strange, and I am thinking we're missing something very basic, as both seem to work fine when isolated. Could it be the order in which your app is configured, can you share relevant portion of app.js where you configure it? Also, how are you defining routes to handle the request?

Comment: thanks for helping. I've added the app.js file above.

Comment: add `app.use(app.router)` as last line in `app.configure()` section.

Comment: `app.listen()` won't work I guess, try this:  `http.createServer(app).listen(8080);`

Comment: added both. Still get an empty response. I use: var user = req.body;
    var header = req.headers;
    console.log('user = ' + JSON.stringify(user)); and in the console user is {}

Comment: Can you update `httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");` to `httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`? Also do `console.log(req.headers)` and paste the results here.

Comment: sorry haven't been able to work on this. until now. I tried all what you wrote and nothing works. req.headers looks fine in the log, but req.body is totally empty. Strangely enough it works to make this request through an iphone but not through an android.

Answer (score 0):

I would first determine if the problem is client side or server side.  Your client code looks ok to me, so I would try hitting your server with a simple `curl` command.

For example:

```
curl -k -i -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-type: application/json' -X POST -d '<YOUR POST BODY>' 'http://yourhost/yourendpoint'
```

This will help determine if it's a purely server side issue, which I suspect in this case it is.

Comment: doing this work. but I still have no idea of how to solve the problem